# Can a person say "I got straight As" if

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

"Straight As" question...

If someone got a B in one subject in the last term, but earned all As in all the subjects at the end of the school year, can they say "I got straight As"? Or do they have to earn all As throughout the school year to be able to say "straight As"?

Comment: straight As usually refers to the end grades, only the final results count. If you were to get a B in a subject at the end of the year, you wouldn't have straight As, but if it was a term before and you recovered, you would.

Comment: It depends how you finish the sentence: "I got straight As *this term*" or "I got straight As *all year.*" The first would be a truthful statement, the second would not. I agree with flumperious, in each case you're talking about end-of-term grades, not whether or not you got a perfect score on each assignment and test along the way

Comment: I should clarify - I you "*get* straight As", you achieve the grades at the end of the year. If you "are a straight A student" you achieve As constantly throughout the year, thus getting a single B at any time would disqualify you from being "a straight A student"